# "invoke-command" using wusa.exe in powershell - won't install the msu

Tags: windows-7, command-line, powershell, hotfix

I'm attempting to push a windows hotfix to a number of computers on our network, using PowerShell v3. I've downloaded the appropriate `.msu` file, I've been able to successfully install it from the local machine on the command line, using:

```
wusa c:\temp\hotfixname.msu /quiet /norestart
```

The problem comes when I try to run it from powershell. We can assume that the msu is already on everyone's machine, at `c:\temp\hotfixname.msu`, and that PSRemoting is already enabled. Here's what I have more or less:

```
import-module ActiveDirectory

$AllPCs = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "Appropriate OU Here" -filter *

$AllPCs | Foreach {
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "$($_.name)" -AsJob -ScriptBlock { 
        if (!(Get-HotFix -id hotfixkb)) { CMD /C "wusa.exe c:\temp\hotfixname.msu /quiet /norestart" }
    }
 }
```

When run like this from my own admin box, running powershell as admin, the local machine opens a `wusa.exe` process for a second or so, before it disappears. Nothing is installed.

I can run `CMD /C "wusa.exe /?`, and it does open the process (it hangs, but only because `wusa` opens its help in a GUI).

I'm out of ideas - does anyone have any advice on this? Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since PSRemoting uses WinRM and according to [this](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2773898) it doesn't look like you can use `wusa.exe` with WinRM or WinRS it doesn't look possible with the code you listed.

There is a workaround listed however:

> Extract the .msu file through Windows Remote Shell with WUSA using the following command:
>
> **winrs.exe -r:%computername% wusa.exe %kb-update% /extract:%destination%**
>
> When complete, install the .cab package with dism.exe or Package Manager. To use dism.exe, use the command below:
>
> **winrs.exe -r:%computername% dism.exe /online /add-package /PackagePath:%Path_To_Package%\KBnnnnnnn.cab**

Comment: We wound up running a scheduled task to force the local PC to run wusa.exe, which seemed to do the trick!

Comment: On my copy of Win 10 v1607 and v1903, I get "The /extract option is no longer supported" when I try to run `wusa.exe` this way

Comment: @Hydrargyrum Try using `expand -f:* myupdate.msu c:\myexpandloc`

Answer (score 0):

remote update of powershell from 3 -> 5.1 (windows7), through the WinRM interface and Ansible server - PSH update-psh.ps1 script (worked for me):

```
# install POWERSHELL update
# descr. wusa: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/934307/description-of-the-windows-update-standalone-installer-in-windows
# descr. dism: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-operating-system-package-servicing-command-line-options 

Start-Process -FilePath 'wusa.exe' -ArgumentList "C:\workit\updatePSH\Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3191566-x64.msu /extract:C:\workit\updatePSH" -Verb RunAs  -Wait -Passthru

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

Start-Process -FilePath 'dism.exe' -ArgumentList "/online /add-package /PackagePath:C:\workit\updatePSH\WSUSSCAN.cab /PackagePath:C:\workit\updatePSH\Windows6.1-KB2809215-x64.cab /PackagePath:C:\workit\updatePSH\Windows6.1-KB2872035-x64.cab /PackagePath:C:\workit\updatePSH\Windows6.1-KB2872047-x64.cab /PackagePath:C:\workit\updatePSH\Windows6.1-KB3033929-x64.cab /PackagePath:C:\workit\updatePSH\Windows6.1-KB3191566-x64.cab /IgnoreCheck /quiet" -Verb RunAs -Wait -PassThru
```

Comment: please fix the formatting of your answer (no need for 'code' tag, just indent relevant lines with 4 spaces ...)